# How to show that an upper bound for the order of an element modulo a prime is met?

Tags: number-theory

Here is the question I am attempting: (Normally I don't like to upload images but I'm not sure exactly what is relevant for the part I'm interested in. It is most likely overkill.)

[image]

Okay so parts $(i)-(iv)$ have caused me no real problems yet $(v)$ has got me stumped in the previous part I have shown that the order of $5$ modulo $p$ is at most $2^{2^{n}}$ since $5^{2^{2^{n}}} \equiv 1 \mod p$. However to show $5$ is a primitive root I need to show $5$ has order $p-1=2^{2^{n}}$ i.e. it actually meets this upper bound for the order. I don't know how to go at this. I tried to assume for a contradiction that the order was less that that (knowing that such an order would divide $2^{2^{n}}$) but got nowhere. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

For (v), it suffices to prove that $p \nmid 5^{(p-1)/2^i}-1=5^{2^{2^n-i}}-1$ for any positive integer $i$. This is obviously true according to (iii) (You can assume contradiction that $\text{ord}_p(5)= \dfrac{p-1}{2^i} \; (i \ge 1)$ and then from (iii) to obtain contradiction).

Thus, that must means $\text{ord}_p(5)=p-1$ or $5$ is primitive root modulo $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Given prime $p=2^{2^n}+1, \phi(p) = 2^{2^n}$, so the order of all numbers coprime to $p$ must divide $2^{2^n}$. In fact they must all be powers of two.

Now if the order of $5 \bmod p$ were less than $2^{2^n}$, it would divide $2^{2^n-1}$ and thus we would find that $5^{2^{2^n-1}} \equiv 1 \bmod p$, which we already know is not true. Therefore the order of  $5 \bmod p$ is indeed ${2^{2^n}}$ and $5$ is a primitive root.